# Why am I getting these error messages when running my R codes within Power BI?

Tags: r, powerbi

I have the following R codes which run just fine inside RStudio. The final output of these codes is a HeatMap plot.

```
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/yahoo.csv")

library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(scales)
library(zoo)
    df$date <- as.Date(df$date)  # format date
df <- df[df$year >= 2012, ]  # filter reqd years

# Create Month Week
df$yearmonth <- as.yearmon(df$date)
df$yearmonthf <- factor(df$yearmonth)
df <- ddply(df,.(yearmonthf), transform, monthweek=1+week-min(week))  # compute week number of month
df <- df[, c("year", "yearmonthf", "monthf", "week", "monthweek", "weekdayf", "VIX.Close")]
# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(monthweek, weekdayf, fill = VIX.Close)) + 
  geom_tile(colour = "white") + 
  facet_grid(year~monthf) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green") +
  labs(x="Week of Month",
       y="",
       title = "Time-Series Calendar Heatmap", 
       subtitle="Yahoo Closing Price", 
       fill="Close")
```

In PowerBI, I have first imported the dataset and then I have inserted an R visual to allow me to paste my R Script. I have pasted my R codes starting with the lines where I am calling the libraries. When running these codes in my PowerBI environment (on Power BI Desktop), I am getting the following error messages:

[image: power bi error message]

Comment: It means that the first line (data import) was not successful, the data.frame `df` not created and R is trying to subset the function `df`.

Comment: How come the data import was not successful when it is showing the whole data set in Power BI?

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with Power Bi. I'm just explaining R's error message.

Comment: have you tried running your code in R before? Maybe your firewall restrictions forbid you from importing from a url? Also, if you already loaded your dataset into powerbi, why download it again in the process (assuming this is the code you tried)?

Comment: @heck1 Yes I have tried it in R and it runs fine. I have downloaded it again in my R Script in Power BI because I can't find a way to assign the loaded dataset to a data frame.

Comment: "because I can't find a way to assign the loaded dataset to a data frame" Maybe you should ask that question instead.